Weights and Biases login to one of multiple accounts not working
I have a team account and a personal account. I want to login to my personal account. Whenever I attempt to login to my personal account, it just brings me back to the team account.
Steps:
Go to wandb website, select “Personal” account from top right menu.
Navigate to user settings.
Reveal API Key, copy.
In a conda environment I want to use wandb in, type:
wandb login --relogin
Then when prompted for the API key, paste the one found as described above.
Next, type “wandb login --verify”. It shows that I’m logged in to my team account.
I can’t get out of this loop, please help.
